# Equation of the surface laplacian of the ellipse curvature

Tags: curvature, laplacian

how can i determine the equation of the surface Laplacian of an ellipse curvature? The ellipse has a=0.3 and b=0.2.

Thanking you in advance for your answer,
Danae

Answer (score 0):

First note that you can use a linear transformation on the plane to transform the ellipse into a unit circle.

Try to determine how the laplacian changes under linear transformations.

Now try to obtain the laplacian induced on the unit circle which is a very simple as the laplacian on the unit circle can simply be defined ad $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$ in polar coordinates.